# Number theory explanation about GCD

Tags: number-theory

" *Note that if a and b are not both zero, then the set of common divisors of a and b is a set of integers taht is bounded above by the largest of a, b , -a, -b. Hence, from the greatest integer principle for the integers, the set has the largest element, so GCD of a and b exists and is unique* "

I am not sure i understand this.

Comment: Any finite set of integers contains a unique maximal element (proof by induction, if nothing else).

Comment: Is there any specific part of this that you don't understand? Are there words or phrases you don't understand, or is it the reasoning you're having trouble with?

Comment: @Arthur How come they have defined set to be a,-a,b,-b . And how dows it follows that GCD is unique from this ?

Comment: For integers with $x|y$ we have $|x| \le |y|$. For positve integers, this boils down to to $x \le y$, which should be obvious (depending on how formal you want the argument to be). But since negative values are allowed, you have to include absolute values, which saying "$a$ and $-a$" is one way to do. Hence it exists and it is unique because the integers are totally ordered, for two different values $x$ and $y$ you cannot both have $x \ge y$ and $y \ge x$. Please note that from this proof it does not at all follow that all other common divisiors of $a$ and $b$ are a divisor of the gcd.

Comment: @ReadThyOwnBook, they include $-a$ and $-b$ because the numbers might be negative.  They could have just said the largest of $|a|$ and $|b|$.  As for why uniqueness of the GCD follows, that's what they're calling the "greatest integer principle." That should be explained somewhere before the excerpt you're quoting.